# Is AdBlocker legal? Can't we get a legal action about AdBlocker as web masters?

Tags: internet, website

> AdBlock is one of the most popular ad blockers worldwide with more
>   than 60 million users on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge as well as
>   Android.

We have calculate that one of our site loss almost $10,000 each year because of AdBlocker.

Simply what they do is, they remove the advertisement which are on our website when a user who use Adblocker visits.

So as a third party, they change the website content just before display it to the user.

Is it legal? Can't we get a legal action about AdBlocker as web masters?

Comment: I'm not sure that they are a "third party", as such. Nothing (?) is routed through their servers; they just provide a tool that runs on the user's computer and which provides filtering at the user's end, no different to any tool that I might legally write myself (had I the skill). And no different (?) to me simply going to make a cup of tea while the advert plays, or choosing not to look at a particular part of the screen.

Comment: Your calculation of "loss" appears to mean "we are prevented from earning because customers who have not agreed to a transaction are allowed to avoid it."  If that holds up, burglars could sue the police for causing loss of earnings.

Answer (score 4):

> Can't we get a legal action about AdBlocker as web masters?

No. I assume that by "web master" you mean a server admin who contracts with entities which are seeking to advertise their goods and services.

An advertiser pays the server to transmit (or send(), in terms of a socket API) certain content to whoever submits a GET or POST request ("the client"). The scope of the contract ends there, and the end consumer or client is not a party to that contract. Any point beyond the server admin's routers, it is perfectly lawful for *end users* to run some program *on the client side* where the purpose of that program is to (1) parse any packets received in the client socket, (2) filter out some of it, (3) and forward the rest to a browser.

Bringing legal action against AdBlocker would be somewhat akin to suing producers of TV remote controls under the allegation that the *mute button* functionality blocks advertisement content.